# show multiple div in colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am trying to show a picture div and a like button div in colorbox. Picture div and like button div are both in other page. And I want to position these div in colorbox different than the page . How can I do that ?

Comment: could you please clarify more what you're trying to do? Maybe put up a screenshot or two and also what you've tried so far as an example on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Moin Zaman I created thumbnail in one page and show the original picture if the thumbnail is clicked . I want to wrap the photo div and like button div in a colorbox . And if I close the colorbox I want to remain in thumbnail page . That is the basic idea (I think facebook also show photos in this way). But I could not figure out mechanism to pull that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#somebutton').click(function(){
            $.colorbox.init();
            $('#divwrapper').show();
            $(this).colorbox({

                        inline:true,
                        href:'#divwrapper',
                        onLoad:function(){ 
                          //do something if you want here
                        },
                        onClosed:function(){

                            $('#divwrapper').hide();
                            $.colorbox.remove();
                        }
                    });


   });
//html side

<div id="divwrapper" style="display:none;">
  <div>Your image here</div>
  <div>Your like button here</div>
</div>

});
```

Comment: the problem is that image and like button is not in the same page where colorbox is initiated .

Comment: I had to create a new div with photo and like button for colorbox.